# Overriding htaccess file extensions line

Tags: .htaccess

I've been having a problem with this htaccess line making images on pages in sub folders not display.

```
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpg|png|mp3|mpg|avi|mov)$ - [F]
```

What would I do in the sub folder .htaccess to suppress this command?

Answer (score 0):

If you have an htaccess file in your root directory and a subdirectory that also has an htaccess file, the subdirectory can bypass all rules in the parent directory's htaccess file by adding a:

```
RewriteEngine On
```

But if you want all other rules to be applied, then you need to add a condition to the rule in your **root directory** to exclude the subdirectory:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subdirectory/
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpg|png|mp3|mpg|avi|mov)$ - [F]
```